# Загрузка ядра linux

Tags: linux, загрузка, kernel, boot

Здраствуйте, решил себе ради интереса создать **linux** дистрибутив.

Собрал ядро, создал загрузочный `ramdisk`, сделал все что мне нужно в `ramdisk`

В итоге у меня вышла такая структура каталогов:

Папка `boot` в ней две папки, первая `initrd`, вторая `kernel`, в первой лежит `main.gz` во второй `kernel.lk`

Как теперь из этого всего сделать `img` образ чтоб запустить в эмуляторе? Гугл сказал что мне нужен загрузчик

Много чего в гугле читал но нормального мануала по установке загрузчика для новичка не нашел.

Мог бы кто расказать подробнее, 
ибо я новичок: первый раз собрал ядро.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотря какой эмулятор используете, например Qemu поддерживает прямую загрузку ядра и рамдиска. Используй параметры

```
-kernel bzImage use 'bzImage' as kernel image
-append cmdline use 'cmdline' as kernel command line
-initrd file    use 'file' as initial ram disk
```

или Воспользуйся `virt-manager` или `virt-install` - хорошие менеджеры для qemu.

На других виртуалках можно воспользоваться GRUB или Syslinux. Для этого создайте образ диска `dd if=/dev/zero of=newos.img bs=10M count=10`. Потом создадим там раздел и файловую систему

```
$ fdisk ./newos.img

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.26.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

На диске не удалось найти таблицу разделов.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xa17f7b6a.

Команда (m для справки): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Номер раздела (1-4, default 1): 1
Первый сектор (2048-20479, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-20479, default 20479): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 9 MiB.

Команда (m для справки): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
$ sudo partx -a ./newos.img
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1
```

Смонтируй луп и скопируй туда папочку /boot/ и установим туда grub: `grub-install --boot-directory=КАТАЛОГ /dev/loop0`

И можно отключить образ `$ partx -d ./newos.img`

В некоторых деталях алгоритм установки скорее всего прийдется подкоректировать. И всеже рекомендую использовать `qemu` для игр с рамдиском ;)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Могли б еще кинуть ссылочек по изучению ядра написания init скрипта и т.д. если розбираетесь в этом?

Comment: Я изучал это дело распаковывая и читая иниты арча, дебиана, опенврт. По литературе не подскажу - я самоучка...

Comment: Сейчас решил это все проделать, но когда дошел до partx -a ./newos.img то получил в ответ ошибку partx: ./newos.img: not a block device

Comment: Ах и еще у меня fdisk не выдал строчку Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 9 MiB.

Comment: @Виталий у меня fdisk новый. может старый не поддерживает файлы для работы или не создалась mbr

Comment: @Виталий у меня fdisk из util-linux 2.26.2 попробовал еще раз - все создалось http://paste.debian.net/171976/

Comment: @Виталий partx тоже из util-linux 2.26.2 у меня. попробуй kpartx. еще вариант сделать /dev/loop вручную и работать с ним вместо файла

Comment: Я собирал это все с arm ноута, возможно в репозиторие дебиана для arm старый fdisk, попробую с компа

Comment: на старом тоже можно собрать. @Виталий, стой.. говоришь arm? может тебе нужна разметка uboot а не mbr в итоге то?

Comment: Если с компа то меня вообще просят установить какието цилиндры "Вы должны установить цилиндры." вот http://pastebin.com/Rk3scFaa

Comment: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/loop прицепи образ на петлю и работай как с блочным устройством. раньше так образы цеплял для восстановления данных

Comment: Нубский вопрос: Сразу после dd if=/dev/zero of=newos.img bs=10M count=1 цеплять и потом fdisk, partx или сначало сделать fdisk и цеплять?

Comment: dd делает файл, вот этот файл цепляешь на loop, потом все операции выполняешь с /dev/loop0 вместо файла

Comment: Неужели... Все вышло. Ура. Большое спасибо

Comment: Вот совсем забыл про qemu-nbd - похож на losetup, но для образов qcow2. Возможно, и для vmdk, vdi сгодится.